# Facebook Send Request Not Sending Request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to set up a Facebook Send Request on my webpage. I have the following code...

```
<a id="invite-friends" onClick="fb_initiate('#{@app_id}')" href="#">Invite your Friends</a>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0">

<script>
  function fb_initiate(app_id) {
    FB.init({
       appId: app_id,
       status:true,
       xfbml:true
    });

    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'There is so much more to life, other than bill payments. Try BillBaba.com and never miss another bill payment.'
     });
   };
</script>
```

When I click on the invite your friends link, the following box loads...

[image]

From there I click on my friends and click on Send Requests. The facebook box closes, however none of my friends have received the message.

My settings are...

[image]

I have no idea how to debug this. Could this be a privacy settings issue or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have a canvas app setup up on Facebook?

Comment: No I don't. I assume that's what I'm missing?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/requests/: _“User-to-user requests are only available for Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the request.”_

Comment: Thanks for the url. I'll check it out.

Comment: @CBroe I've set up the Canvas app with my `canvas url` and `secure canvas url` however it's still not working. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your application is in sandbox mode. You can find that in the Basic Info section. 
If sandbox mode is on, the apprequest will be sent only to the developers or testers associated with the app.

Add your friends as developers or testers and they will receive the apprequests.

Comment: Thank you!! I would have never figured that out on my own.